# Generating SLD files from Autodesk's layer

Tags: sld, autodesk

I have Autodesk layer files (with `.layer` suffix).

I'd like to create SLD files based on these layer's information (e.g. the colors). I tried to generate the SLD XML file by using `xslt` and parsing the layer files.

Does anyone have a better solution for generating SLD files?

Comment: What was the result, when you used `xslt`? And what do you expect from another solution?